# What species of bear are most and least dangerous to humans?

Tags: safety, bears

Excluding hybrids it seems like there are [eight species of bears.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bears)

Which are most and least likely to injure or kill a human?

Related [Do black, brown/grizzly or polar bears ever prey on humans?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/do-black-brown-grizzly-or-polar-bears-ever-prey-on-humans)

Related [Is any subspecies of black bear more -- or less -- aggressive than another?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/is-any-subspecies-of-black-bear-more-or-less-aggressive-than-another)

Comment: Doing this as a comment because not detailed and sourced enough. Generally medium sized bears like black bears are most aggressive, because they aren't big enough to be safe from say a moose or a wolf family. Large brown bears are less likely to attack, except when with young. Polar Bears are more predatory than others, and more likely to attack out of a lack of food. Small species like sun bears, spectacled bears and sloth bears are of least concern as far as bears go, they only fight something our size if it attacks them. These bears can still kill a person, but are much less likely to try.

Comment: (Giant pandas are in that last category as well by the way, they are the exception among large herbivores for not being equally dangerous to predators.)

Comment: It mostly depend on where you are. Here the biggest risk is an escaped zoo animal, when in Churchill Canada, it was a polar bear and farther south the risk was of a darker shaded bear.

Comment: @Monster I disagree with your characterization of black bears.  Black bears in the California Sierra and the Colorado Rockies (the only ones I know well) avoid or retreat from people.  The saying among the hikers I knew in CA was that black bears think humans are large animals; brown bears think humans are small animals.  Of course, one has to respect black bears and be cautious when in the vicinity of one.

Comment: you may want to reference the question about whether [some subspecies (of which there are 16) of black bear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/is-any-subspecies-of-black-bear-more-or-less-aggressive-than-another) are more aggressive than others.

Comment: @ab2 added, missed that one when I was browsing.

Comment: Teddy bears, perhaps?

Comment: @Loren Pechtel Did you read my [meta question](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/how-to-get-across-that-a-bear-is-not-a-bear-is-not-a-bear) (See last paragraph) or is this a case of great minds drifting in the same channel?

Comment: @ab2 Didn't see your question, although it's an obvious answer.  The other alternative is the drop bear.